# How to force a link to open a new broswer session in Joomla

Tags: joomla, browser

Joomla allows me to open a new browser window and a new tab, but I'd like to force a link to open a brand new browser session. This would allow someone to have two different sessions of the same program open without conflict. I see that I can do this with javascript, but if anyone knows how to do it easily within the Joomla CMS, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Not within Joomla it's self but you could easily build an extension or there maybe one already out there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without a core hack, since Joomla authentication is based on session and you would need to change that to get or custom-named cookies or session vars